# Javascript cancel button is submitting form

Tags: javascript, alert

I am trying to add a javascript alert to my form, the problem I am having is that when the user clicks cancel, the form  still gets submitted?.

In the head I have :

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmDelete() {if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category ?'))
alert('Category Deleted !');
else alert('Cancelled !')}
</script>
</head>
```

My link uses the following :

```
a onClick="confirmDelete()"
```

Im not sure why clicking cancel still submits it?, is it possible to show Cancelled ! for 2 seconds and then close also ?.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the result from the confirm:

```
function confirmDelete() {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category ?');
}


onClick="confirmDelete()"
```

Comment: If I change the onClick event to onClick="return confirmDelete()" Cancel still submits the form ?

Comment: Any function that does not specify a return result automatically returns undefined. Wouldn't this resolve to false? Just wondering, I don't have the answer myself.

Comment: Thanks, thats sorted it now :-)

Comment: @IainSimpson I noticed afterwards that you do not return from the function and corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

try using the cancel

```
function confirmDelete(e) {
 if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category ?'))
   alert('Category Deleted !');
 else {
  alert('Cancelled !');
  e.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

and change your onclick to

```
onclick="confirmDelete(event)"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery click event and inside event put `e.preventDefault();` and it will prevent default and default is submiting form-

Comment: @roccp337 `preventDefault()` is also in standard [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).